# Storybook Failed in Very First Try in New Create-React-App

Tags: create-react-app, storybook

I'm a junior front-end, and trying to learn Storybook for work.
I just created new react app with `create-react-app` and run `npm start`.
And it failed just in the screenshot below.
[npm start failed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTEdo.png)

But I just solved  it after seeing an answer from stack-overflow just like in the screenshot below.
[solved error of react-scripts@4.0.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJV2C.png)

And I initiated storybook in my new react project with `npx sb init` just like the documentation says. It is succeed by creating `.storybook` folder and some example stories under `src` folder. Then, I run `npm run storybook`, and so many error appears in the console.

```html
$ npm run storybook

> learn-storybook-5@0.1.0 storybook
> start-storybook -p 6006 -s public

info @storybook/react v6.4.9
info
(node:15528) DeprecationWarning: --static-dir CLI flag is deprecated, see:

https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#deprecated---static-dir-cli-flag
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
info => Loading presets
info Found existing addon "@storybook/addon-docs", skipping.   
info Found existing addon "@storybook/addon-actions", skipping.
info => Serving static files from ./public at /
info => Loading Webpack configuration from `node_modules\react-scripts`
info => Removing existing JavaScript and TypeScript rules.
info => Modifying Create React App rules.
info => Using default Webpack4 setup     
10% building 1/1 modules 0 activeWARN Expected '@storybook/addon-docs' (or '@storybook/addon-essentials') to be listed before '@storybook/addon-controls' (or '@storybook/addon-essentials') in main Storybook config.
13% building 27/33 modules 6 active D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@pmmmwh\react-refresh-webpack-plugin\client\utils\safeThis.js       
info => Using cached manager
webpack built preview d035dbd78ee6247b1305 in 9381ms
× ｢wdm｣: Hash: d035dbd78ee6247b1305
Version: webpack 4.44.2
Time: 9381ms
Built at: 12/10/2021 3:29:06 PM
                                  Asset      Size        Chunks                                Chunk Names
                     0.iframe.bundle.js   226 KiB             0  [emitted]
                 0.iframe.bundle.js.map   215 KiB             0  [emitted] [dev]
                     1.iframe.bundle.js   206 KiB             1  [emitted]
                 1.iframe.bundle.js.map   145 KiB             1  [emitted] [dev]
                     2.iframe.bundle.js  9.15 KiB             2  [emitted]
                 2.iframe.bundle.js.map  6.47 KiB             2  [emitted] [dev]
                     3.iframe.bundle.js  92.4 KiB             3  [emitted]
                 3.iframe.bundle.js.map  84.3 KiB             3  [emitted] [dev]
                     4.iframe.bundle.js   372 KiB             4  [emitted]              [big]
                 4.iframe.bundle.js.map   412 KiB             4  [emitted] [dev]
                     5.iframe.bundle.js  15.7 KiB             5  [emitted]
                 5.iframe.bundle.js.map  16.6 KiB             5  [emitted] [dev]
                    asset-manifest.json  1.67 KiB                [emitted]
                            iframe.html  11.4 KiB                [emitted]
                  main.iframe.bundle.js   111 KiB          main  [emitted]                     main
              main.iframe.bundle.js.map    43 KiB          main  [emitted] [dev]               main
          runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js  37.9 KiB  runtime~main  [emitted]                     runtime~main
      runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js.map  39.2 KiB  runtime~main  [emitted] [dev]               runtime~main
static/media/code-brackets.2e1112d7.svg  1.42 KiB                [emitted] [immutable]
       static/media/colors.a4bd0486.svg  8.31 KiB                [emitted] [immutable]
     static/media/comments.a3859089.svg  1.49 KiB                [emitted] [immutable]
    static/media/direction.b770f9af.svg  1.25 KiB                [emitted] [immutable]
         static/media/flow.edad2ac1.svg  1.36 KiB                [emitted] [immutable]
       static/media/plugin.d494b228.svg  2.12 KiB                [emitted] [immutable]
         static/media/repo.6d496322.svg   1.6 KiB                [emitted] [immutable]
     static/media/stackalt.dba9fbb3.svg  2.49 KiB                [emitted] [immutable]
          vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js  4.64 MiB  vendors~main  [emitted]              [big]  vendors~main
      vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js.map  4.16 MiB  vendors~main  [emitted] [dev]               vendors~main
Entrypoint main [big] = runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js.map vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js.map main.iframe.bundle.js main.iframe.bundle.js.map
[0] multi ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ErrorOverlayEntry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined ./storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/esm/client/preview/config-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addParameter.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-outline/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./generated-stories-entry.js 232 bytes {main} [built]
[./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js] 3.91 KiB {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[./generated-stories-entry.js] 2.95 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ErrorOverlayEntry.js] 2.38 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js] 500 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js-generated-config-entry.js] 699 bytes {vendors~main} [built] [failed] [1 error]       
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js] 704 bytes {vendors~main} [built] [failed] [1 error]  
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js] 708 bytes {vendors~main} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addParameter.js-generated-config-entry.js] 708 bytes {vendors~main} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-config-entry.js] 706 bytes {vendors~main} [built] [failed] [1 error][./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-config-entry.js] 705 bytes {vendors~main} [built] [failed] [1 error] 
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js] 702 bytes {vendors~main} [built] [failed] [1 error]    
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js] 704 bytes {vendors~main} [built] [failed] [1 error]  
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-outline/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js] 704 bytes {vendors~main} [built] [failed] [1 error]  
[./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js] 105 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
    + 1184 hidden modules

ERROR in ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\.storybook\preview.js-generated-config-entry.js: Missing semicolon. (8:118)

   6 |
   7 | /* eslint-disable import/no-unresolved */
>  8 | import { addDecorator, addParameters, addLoader, addArgsEnhancer, addArgTypesEnhancer, setGlobalRender } from 'D:/311's learning/learn-storybook-5/node_modules/@storybook/client-api';
     |                                                                                                                       ^
   9 | import { logger } from 'D:/311's learning/learn-storybook-5/node_modules/@storybook/client-logger';
  10 | import * as config from 'D:/311's learning/learn-storybook-5/.storybook/preview.js';
  11 | Object.keys(config).forEach(function (key) {
    at Object._raise (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:541:17)
    at Object.raiseWithData (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:534:17)
    at Object.raise (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:495:17)
    at Object.semicolon (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3550:10)
    at Object.parseImport (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14831:10)
    at Object.parseStatementContent (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13454:27)
    at Object.parseStatement (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13352:17)
    at Object.parseStatement (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5307:24)
    at Object.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13941:25)
    at Object.parseBlockBody (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13932:10)
    at Object.parseProgram (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13272:10)
    at Object.parseTopLevel (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13263:25)
    at Object.parseTopLevel (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:6273:28)
    at Object.parse (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15037:10)
    at parse (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15089:38)
    at parser (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\parser\index.js:52:34)
 @ multi ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ErrorOverlayEntry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined ./storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/esm/client/preview/config-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addParameter.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-outline/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./generated-stories-entry.js main[16]

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js-generated-config-entry.js 8:118
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:118)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| /* eslint-disable import/no-unresolved */
> import { addDecorator, addParameters, addLoader, addArgsEnhancer, addArgTypesEnhancer, setGlobalRender } from 'D:/311's learning/learn-storybook-5/node_modules/@storybook/client-api';
| import { logger } from 'D:/311's learning/learn-storybook-5/node_modules/@storybook/client-logger';
| import * as config from 'D:/311's learning/learn-storybook-5/node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js';
 @ multi ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ErrorOverlayEntry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined ./storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/esm/client/preview/config-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addParameter.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-outline/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./generated-stories-entry.js main[15]
 
 Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
                          Asset      Size               Chunks  Chunk Names
    __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  6.28 KiB  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/templates/index.ejs] 2.03 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} 
[built]
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\.storybook\preview.js-generated-config-entry.js: Missing semicolon. (8:118)

   6 |
   7 | /* eslint-disable import/no-unresolved */
>  8 | import { addDecorator, addParameters, addLoader, addArgsEnhancer, addArgTypesEnhancer, setGlobalRender } from 'D:/311's learning/learn-storybook-5/node_modules/@storybook/client-api';
     |                                                                                                                       ^
   9 | import { logger } from 'D:/311's learning/learn-storybook-5/node_modules/@storybook/client-logger';
  10 | import * as config from 'D:/311's learning/learn-storybook-5/.storybook/preview.js';
  11 | Object.keys(config).forEach(function (key) {
    at Object._raise (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:541:17)
    at Object.raiseWithData (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:534:17)
    at Object.raise (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:495:17)
    at Object.semicolon (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3550:10)
    at Object.parseImport (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14831:10)
    at Object.parseStatementContent (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13454:27)
    at Object.parseStatement (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13352:17)
    at Object.parseStatement (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5307:24)
    at Object.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13941:25)
    at Object.parseBlockBody (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13932:10)
    at Object.parseProgram (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13272:10)
    at Object.parseTopLevel (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13263:25)
    at Object.parseTopLevel (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:6273:28)
    at Object.parse (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15037:10)
    at parse (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15089:38)
    at parser (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\parser\index.js:52:34)
    at D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:118)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| /* eslint-disable import/no-unresolved */
> import { addDecorator, addParameters, addLoader, addArgsEnhancer, addArgTypesEnhancer, setGlobalRender } from 'D:/311's learning/learn-storybook-5/node_modules/@storybook/client-api';
| import { logger } from 'D:/311's learning/learn-storybook-5/node_modules/@storybook/client-logger';
| import * as config from 'D:/311's learning/learn-storybook-5/node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js';
    at handleParseError (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:469:19)
    at D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4
    at D:\311's learning\learn-storybook-5\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:85:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
    
WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.
```

I searched with possible keywords from the error on google and in-and-out stack-overflow links. I installed some addon in `.storybook/main.js` file. But nothing works. Below are my package.json file and two config file of storybook.

```html
//package.json

{
  "name": "learn-storybook-5",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.2.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.9"
  }
}
```

```html
//.storybook/main.js

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/node-logger',
    '@storybook/addon-docs',
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
}
```

```html
//.storybook/preview.js

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```

It has been two days that I can't even boost up stroybook :))
I hope someone could guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my folder name `3ll's learning`.
The single quote from my folder name conflicts with paths used in Stroybook's modules. That's it. Admin from Storybook discord server pointed out that to me.